# How to make use of 'Power ON Reset' while there is noise in Power?

Tags: microcontroller, reset, cortex-m0

I'm using Nuc240LE3AE(Cortex M0) to run a code that is developed.
I want to run the code on startup for which (POR)Power On Reset facility is used.
Normally this is Enabled in the Micro-controller and as per the datasheet;

> When powered on, the POR circuit generates a reset signal to reset the whole chip function, but noise on the power may cause the POR active again. User can disable internal POR circuit to avoid unpredictable noise to cause chip reset by writing 0x5AA5 to this field.
>          The POR function will be active again when this field is set to another value or chip is reset by other reset source, including:
>   nRESET, Watchdog Timer reset, Window Watchdog Timer reset, LVR reset, BOD reset, ICE reset command and the software-chip reset function

The code works perfectly on Development board during startup but in the target board so developed, is restarting itself after sometime as mentioned in the datasheet due to noise(assumption).
But if I disable POR in the code, does the Micro-controller fails to execute the code at 'Power On' from next time onwards (In case of power failure)? if so, How can I overcome this situation?

Comment: It might be a good time to look at the good answers you have previously received on earlier questions and start formally accepting them. Look at it as a kind-of fee you pay for getting good advice.

Comment: Take this question. Alongside Michael's answer (to the left below the upvote/downvote buttons) is a symbol of a circle with a tick/check inside (only you can see it). If you use your mouse and click on that symbol, it goes green indicating that you have formally accepted that answer and Michael gets rewarded with both a nice feeling and 15 reputation points. I'm not saying you do it for this answer right away (because it's always worth waiting a day or so to see what other answers might pop-up)  but, if after a day or so, Michael's answer is the best (in your opinion), then press that button.

Comment: Except that you shouldn't accept a answer so quickly, in this case within two hours of asking the question.  I originally went into this question because I saw it had no accepted answer.  I read the question and was going to respond, but then saw that a answer had already been accepted.  There's no point wasting my time here now.  A good rule is to wait either 24 hours or until at least 3 answers before accepting.

Comment: Will consider next time.. but please answer it if you have any better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the snippet from the data sheet that you show in our question you need to provide for another reset source. My suggestion is that you look into power on reset chips and use one of those to drive the nRESET pin on your MCU.

There are a plethora of suitable devices that can be used for this purpose. If you are using a 3.3V power supply to the microcontroller you could try the MCP120-300 as a possible solution. It is a small three pin reset generator in a SOT-23 package.

Answer (score 1):

Your plan to disable POR, even if that seems to work, risks being a "sticking plaster" (sometimes called a "Band Aid") which is hiding a deeper problem that you do not understand and have not really solved. The *real* problem might then "come back and bite you" later.

Therefore instead of considering disabling Power-On Reset, you should be investigating deeper why your "target board", but not your "development board", is "restarting itself".

You said that:

> the target board so developed, is restarting itself after sometime as mentioned in the datasheet due to noise(assumption).

I'm glad you said this was an assumption, as it shows you realise the need to differentiate between assumptions and deductions. Your approach should be to find the *real* cause of your "target board" restarting. Only when you know the cause, should you then consider how to solve the problem.

*Don't guess at a "solution" without really knowing the cause of the problem!*

From a quick look at the [NuMicro 240 series datasheet](http://www.nuvoton.com/hq/resource-download.jsp?tp_GUID=DA00-NUC230/240) ([direct PDF link](http://www.nuvoton.com/resource-files/DS_NUC230_240%28AE%29_Series_EN_Rev1.01.pdf)) and the [NuMicro 240 series technical reference manual](http://www.nuvoton.com/hq/resource-download.jsp?tp_GUID=DA05-NUC230/240) ([direct PDF link](http://www.nuvoton.com/resource-files/TRM_NUC230_240%28AE%29_Series_EN_Rev1.03.pdf)) there is an `RSTSRC` register, which holds flags to show the reason for the last restart e.g. Brown Out Detector (BOD), Low Voltage Reset (LVR) etc.

The information from that register after an unexpected restart, along with using an oscilloscope to check the quality of the power supply voltage, will allow you to make progress on your investigation.

Also note that there can also be software causes for a board to "restart itself", not only hardware causes. Don't assume that the cause must be related to hardware (e.g. power) until you have evidence for that.